# How to create an "unique" contraint in MongoDB through Hibernate OGM and JPA

Tags: mongodb, jpa, hibernate-ogm

I'm trying to define a unique constraint on a non-id field. The answer might seem obvious:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"col1"}))
public class MyEntity { ... }
```

However, this is not working. I've checked the indexes in the collection through the `mongo` command line, but there is no trace of a unique index (only a `_id_` index is being generated).

I have also tried with the `@Index` annotation without joy:

```
@Entity
@Table(indexes={ @Index(name = "myIndex", columnList="col1", unique = true) })
public class MyEntity { ... }
```

The `@Column(unique = true)` annotation doesn't have any effect either.

How can I get Hibernate OGM to create a unique index for this collection?

Thank you in advance,

Guillermo

Comment: does Hibernate OGM even claim to support unique constraints yet? I know DataNucleus JPA does, but not tried with Hibernate OGM

Comment: The Hibernate OGM documentation on the MongoDB dialect doesn't say a word about it (none that I could find, at least). However, if I introduce a wrong column name in either `columnNames` or `columnList` attributes, Hibernate OGM complains about it. Moreover, when I use `@UniqueContraint` or `@Column(unique = true)` annotations, the Hibernate OGM logs explicitly state that the field has `unique = true`. So there is some processing going on about this in the background...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate OGM does not yet consider this index/constraint meta-data for MongoDB. I've opened [OGM-910](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-910) for tracking it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification and for filling a new feature request ticket @Gunnar.